# NLP to SQl query mapping algorithm which is independent of the database on which it is applied

Tags: c#, sql, database, dynamic, nlp

user gives me an excel sheet and asks questions pertaining to that sheet in english. I need to construct  one/set of sql queries from his question so that i can execute them and return the output to the user. 
Identifying the column names, data values,arithmetic operators in the user entered question did work for some questions.But my code returns the same output for the following two queries which is wrong

show me states and their sales for state = texas

show me all the states which have sales equal to that of texas

*here 'state' , 'sales' are column names. 'texas' is a data value in the column 'states'

Whatever papers i have read so far only do NLP to SQL mapping for a specific database.I have also tried stanford lexicalized parser for dependencies, clauseIE algorithm for clause extraction. But nothing that i have tried gave me desired results.

any lead in the right direction will be appreciated

Comment: you mean there is no possible way to solve this problem ? i dont need 100% accuracy..40% accuracy is good enough.. i can improve it using some machine learning algorithms

Comment: We're veering into opinion/philosophy territory here... but what you've described seems to be an AI-hard problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI-complete). Translating any natural language query into any SQL database query (without regard to domain, etc.) would likely require human-level intelligence. There are some research/commercial projects active in this space, but they all require a significant amount of manual effort for domain adaptation.

TL;DR: You'll have more luck teaching business people to write SQL queries rather than trying to automate this process yourself.